# Removing comments completely in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

After I've resolved a comment in a Google Spreadsheet, is there a way to delete the whole comment email chain which is currently stored in the comment button on the top right hand side of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - there is a small dropdown menu in the top right corner of the comments menu:

[image: Spreadsheet comments menu]

Click the *Delete* menu item, and the comment thread is gone.